# Does babel config json support baseUrl like ts config json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

As we know typescript config json support baseUrl option so that we cannot avoid using a path word multiple times while declaring path aliases. But I couldn't able to find an option for this in babel config json.

This is my tsconfig.json, here I can use the baseUrl "./src" instead of adding it in front of every paths.

```
{
  ......
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"],
      "@features/*": ["features/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

But see here in babel.config.js file, I have to use the "./src" in front of every path aliases.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          '@features': './src/features/',
          '@components': './src/components/'
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```